# Replace the values of one column with the mean of values of this column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the follow dadaset called "snp_sol" that have 481974 rows:

```
 trait     effect     snp       chr      pos   snp_effect      weight          variance_explained        var_a_hat
  1         2         1         1        54  0.2030156E-02   1.251482                  0                    0
  1         2         2         1       689 -0.3726744E-03  0.9660012                  0                    0
  1         2         3         1      1234  0.4801369E-03  0.9823542                  0                    0 
  1         2         4         1      1280 -0.1104844E-03  0.9272357                  0                    0
  1         2         5         1      2610 -0.1296295E-02   1.115933                  0                    0
 ...       ...       ...       ...     ...    ...            ...                     ...                   ...

  1         2    481971        26   4897157 -0.7846317E-04  0.9226092                  0                    0
  1         2    481972        26   4898314 -0.3934468E-03  0.9691408                  0                    0
  1         2    481973        26   4898376 -0.7204678E-03   1.019935                  0                    0
  1         2    481974        26   4898606 -0.1522481E-03  0.9333048                  0                    0
```

I want to get the mean of each 50 values (windows) in the seventh column (weight) and this mean should appear in the place of the values that originate it, as below:

```
trait     effect     snp       chr      pos   snp_effect               weight                variance_explained      var_a_hat
  1         2         1         1        54  0.2030156E-02      mean of first 50 rows              0                    0
 ...       ...       ...       ...     ...    ...                        ...                      ...                  ...

  1         2        50         1      4234  0.5801369E-03      mean of first 50 rows              0                    0
  1         2        51         1      5080 -0.5048544E-03  mean of second set of 50 rows          0                    0
 ...       ...       ...       ...     ...    ...                        ...                      ...                  ...

  1         2       100         1     12050 -0.4854433E-03  mean of second set of 50 rows          0                    0 
  1         2       101         1     14080 -0.3554433E-03   mean of third set of 50 rows          0                    0 
 ...       ...       ...       ...     ...    ...                        ...                      ...                  ...

  1         2       150         1     14080 -0.7894433E-03   mean of third set of 50 rows          0                    0 

 and so on

  1         2    481974        26   4898606 -0.1522481E-03        mean of last rows                0                    0
```

Note that there should be no windows overlap and in the last window can not have 50 rows.

I'm was trying this code:

```
NR=$(wc -l "snp_sol" | awk '{print $1}')  # Count the number rows
window=$((NR/50))             # Defining the number windows
int=${window%.*}              # Converting to interger
it=$((2*int))                 # Double the number of windows
for i in $(seq 0 50 $it)          # for statement with a seq to count the windows
    do
    vi=$i                    # Variable to define the beginning of the window       
    vf=$((vi+50))           # Variable to define the end of window
    awk -v vi="$vi" -v vf="$vf" '{ if(NR > vi && NR <= vf)  # take each window
        print } ' snp_sol > b.txt                          # new temporary file to receive the window 
        m=$(awk '{sum+=$7} END {m=sum/NR; print m}' b.txt) # Calculate the mean
    awk -v mean="$m" '{print $1=$3,$2=mean}' b.txt > $i.temp  # save a temporary file with the mean in second column
    rm b.txt      # Remove the file created to calculate the mean
done
cat *.temp > b.temp   # join all temporary files in sequence
paste snp_sol b.temp > c.temp  
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7=$11,$8,$9=$10}'  c.temp > snp_sol
rm *.temp
```

However, this is not working. There must be another way to do it, but I don't know how to do it.

The solution of this situation can be preferably using shell script.

Please, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `datamash`, `split` (GNU coreutils) and `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove header line and split `input_file` into n files `split00000`, `split00001`...
# with max. 4 lines each (use `-l50` for your data file)
split -d -a5 -l4 <(tail -n+2 input_file) split

{   head -n1 input_file      # add header
    for fsplit in split*; do
        mean=$(datamash -W mean 7 < "$fsplit") # calculate mean value
        awk -v mean="$mean" '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,mean,$8,$9 }' "$fsplit"
    done
} | column -t > output_file  # format as table and write result

rm split*                    # cleanup
```

In this script I used your data (dotted lines removed) as input and only 4 values for the mean value.
Replace `-l4` with `-l50` for your data file in the script. This is pretty much the same as you did, I just let `split` and `datamash` do all the work.

Input file:

```
$ cat input_file
trait     effect     snp       chr      pos   snp_effect      weight          variance_explained        var_a_hat
  1         2         1         1        54  0.2030156E-02   1.251482                  0                    0
  1         2         2         1       689 -0.3726744E-03  0.9660012                  0                    0
  1         2         3         1      1234  0.4801369E-03  0.9823542                  0                    0
  1         2         4         1      1280 -0.1104844E-03  0.9272357                  0                    0
  1         2         5         1      2610 -0.1296295E-02   1.115933                  0                    0
  1         2    481971        26   4897157 -0.7846317E-04  0.9226092                  0                    0
  1         2    481972        26   4898314 -0.3934468E-03  0.9691408                  0                    0
  1         2    481973        26   4898376 -0.7204678E-03   1.019935                  0                    0
  1         2    481974        26   4898606 -0.1522481E-03  0.9333048                  0                    0
```

Result:

```
$ cat output_file
trait  effect  snp     chr  pos      snp_effect      weight       variance_explained  var_a_hat
1      2       1       1    54       0.2030156E-02   1.031768275  0                   0
1      2       2       1    689      -0.3726744E-03  1.031768275  0                   0
1      2       3       1    1234     0.4801369E-03   1.031768275  0                   0
1      2       4       1    1280     -0.1104844E-03  1.031768275  0                   0
1      2       5       1    2610     -0.1296295E-02  1.0069045    0                   0
1      2       481971  26   4897157  -0.7846317E-04  1.0069045    0                   0
1      2       481972  26   4898314  -0.3934468E-03  1.0069045    0                   0
1      2       481973  26   4898376  -0.7204678E-03  1.0069045    0                   0
1      2       481974  26   4898606  -0.1522481E-03  0.9333048    0                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v mod=50 '
     BEGIN{ if(!mod) {mod=50} };

     NR==1 {print;next};

     (NR+1) % mod == 0 {
       $7=sum/count;
       print;
       sum=count=0;
       next;
     };

     {count++; sum+=$7}

     END {
       if (((NR+1) % mod)) != 0) {
         $7=sum/count;
         print;
       };
     }' snp_sol
```

This prints the header line unmodified.  Then, for every 50th input line it replaces the value in $7 with the calculated mean and prints the line.  It also does the same on the final input line **iff** it wasn't previously printed.

For all other lines of input, it increments `count` (a line counter) and adds `$7` to `sum` (which contains the sum of all $7 values in that block of `mod` input lines).

No temporary files, no repeat runs over the same data, no shell loop forking `awk` multiple times.  Just one simple pass through the input file, with a very simple algorithm.

NOTE: A variable called `mod` is used instead of hard-coding 50 as the modulus.  This defaults to 50 if it isn't specified on the command line with, e.g., `-v mod=n`.